# Duda acerca de los triggers en T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, trigger, tsql

Hasta donde he entendido, cuando un trigger se ejecuta para el evento insert, los nuevos registros se añaden a una tabla virtual llamada inserted.

Cuando se ejecuta para un evento delete, los registros borrados se añaden a una tabla temporal denominada deleted.

Pero cuando se ejecuta para un evento update, los registros que vamos a actualizar antes de dicha actualización se añaden a la tabla deleted, y y los mismos registros ya actualizados se añaden a la tabla inserted.

Mi duda es: ¿por qué para el evento update no se añaden a una tabla temporal que se llame updated o algo por el estilo? ¿Por qué tienen que añadirse antes y después de la actualización a esas dos tablas?.

Comment: Sergio, del `update` casi podríamos decir que no existe, ya que  se compone de un `delete` y un `insert`. Por consiguiente, en un trigger se manejan las pseudo-tablas `deleted` e `inserted` por que son justamente las dos acciones con las que se construye el `update`. Por otro lado que valores debería hipotéticamente  tener tu pseudo-tabla `updated`, ¿el valor anterior? ¿el valor posterior?, ¿los dos?. Los dos primeros ya los tenemos, el último lo podríamos construir haciendo un `union` entre `inserted` y `deleted`

Comment: Realizas una pregunta que solamente el diseñador original de esta parte de Sysbase/SQLServer podría responder. No hay una respuesta canónica a tu pregunta.